# C parameter does not affect accuracy in libsvm

Tags: c#, svm, libsvm

I am facing a weird situation while using libsvm and in particular its C# implementation [svm.net](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html). I perform a grid search in order to detect the best value for parameter C (I am using a linear kernel). However, it seems that the first value of C that is tried sets the accuracy of the machine: all other values that the grid search tries for it yield the very same accuracy, unless I re-run the search on a differently shuffled dataset.

This leaves me quite puzzled. Does anyone have an idea of what may cause this behavior? I am pretty new to support vector machines, so I might have overlooked something obvious. Thanks.

EDIT: The method I call is the following: 
        `ParameterSelection.Grid(problems.training, problems.validation, parameters, MIN_C, .MAX_C,STEP_C, out current_C, out current_accuracy, out tmp_model);`
which is a method I built similarly to the already existing ParameterSelection.Grid methods provided by the library. More in detail, here is the code:

```
  public static void Grid(Problem training, Problem validation, Parameter parameters, double min_c, double max_c, double step_c, out double C,
        out double accuracy, out Model best_model)
    {
        C = 0;
        accuracy = 0;
        best_model = null;
        double maxScore = double.MinValue;
        for (double index = min_c; index < max_c; index += step_c)
        {
            parameters.C = index;
            Model model = Training.Train(training, parameters);
            double test = Prediction.Predict(validation, null, model, false);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", parameters.C, test);
            if (test > maxScore)
            {
                C = parameters.C;
                maxScore = test;
                accuracy = test;
                best_model = model;
                Debug.WriteLine(" New Maximum! C =" + C);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of code with the grid search?

Comment: What is the value of the `test`? Is it close to zero on each iteration?

Comment: No, it is around 0.8 (with an oscillation depending on the current ordering of the dataset). However, it stays the very same at each iteration.

Comment: Have you tried [libsvm.net librairy](http://nicolaspanel.github.io/libsvm.net/)?

Comment: What are the C values that you are checking? The most obvious reason for this is that you are trying a too narrow range of values. In fact it looks like this, as th emost common choices of C's are in the form of a^i, not i*a (which you use now)